# tkinter python3 RC522

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, frame, mifare

I'm creating a GUI using tkinter which displays the information from RC522 rfid card. Here, I want that for every 0.5 seconds, the rfid will write itself a new data by adding 100 from its previous data. The rc522 script is based on https://github.com/simonmonk/clever_card_kit (read.py, write.py,SimpleMFRC522.py)

```
Class rcinfo(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, master)
self.master = master

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
continue_reading = True
reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()

while continue_reading:
text = reader.read()
info = tk.StringVar
label = tk.Label(master, text = ' ', bg="white", textvariable=info, font=("Calibri",16,bold))
label.place(x=100, y=100, width=600, height=85)
info.set(text)

me = int(text) + 100        ///// convert previous value to integer and add 100
text = str(me)              ///// convert 'me' to string
text = reader.write(text)   ///// new data is written

time.sleep(0.5)
continue_reading = True

GPIO.cleanup()
```

However, when this script is run, the error says

> File "/home/pi/Readme/Readme.py", line 137, in **init**
>       me = int(text) + 100
>       TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Please help. I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Start by examining what `text` is before trying to convert it to an int. You are assuming it's something different than what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your `text` variable is not allowed to be converted to an int because it's not a `str` or another number type - it's a tuple.

To see what the tuple contains, you could `print(text)` after assigning it and see what output you get. My guess is you need to directly access an element of the tuple to get the data you're after:

`me = int(text) + 100` becomes `me = int(text[0]) + 100`.